# Getting a cmake executable path to run it on a custom command

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating an executable using the `add_executable(foo sources.cpp)` then I would like to have a target that runs foo, so right now I'm doing this:

```
add_custom_target(run_foo 
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/foo 
   DEPENDS foo 
   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

it works now, but I feel like I'm doing it wrong by hardcoding the path to the binary in "COMMAND". Isn't there a way to get the path to the binary from `foo` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_custom_target(COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:foo> ...)
```

See:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't even need a generator expression :)
At least /w [modern CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=COMMAND):

> If COMMAND specifies an executable target name (created by the add_executable() command) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time.

```
add_executable(foo ...)
add_custom_target(COMMAND foo ...)
```